# Expression can not be use as a function error

Tags: c++

I am getting compilation error expression cannot be use as  function at the constructor initialization.

```
class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port,ConnectionReceiver* r)
:acceptor_(io_service,tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port),receiver(r))
{
  start_accept();
}

private:
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  ConnectionReceiver* receiver;
};
```

Comment: You have a close parentheses in the wrong place.  Try `)),receiver(r)`

Comment: There's something wrong with brackets in `acceptor_` initialization. Did you mean `acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),receiver(r)`?

Comment: Don't edit your question to fix the error, leave it like that.